# Преобразование SVG в векторные PDF,PS

Tags: batik, pdf, php, imagemagick, svg

Добрый день, сообщество!

**Что имеется:** программно сформированный на сервере валидный SVG, внутри в основном path. Серверный код на php, поэтому решение предпочтительно для php.

**Что требуется:** получить PDF, PS, а также PSD(по возможности) содержащие ВЕКТОРНЫЙ рисунок такой же как в исходном SVG. В случае PDF это будет встроенный SVG, для остальных не знаю.

**Что пробовал:** MagickWand(ImageMagick) - с удовольствием конвертирует, практически что угодно и во что угодно, особенно удачно получается PNG (даже с прозрачностью). Но есть одна большая проблема, которая все плюсы сводит на нет. При конвертации SVG в PDF, EPS, PS, PSD, растрирует исходный рисунок.

**Что уже посмотрел:** но не совсем разобрался:
 1. Apache Batik, не совсем понятно как работать и что будет на выходе. Можно конечно через exec запускать яву, но как к этому отнесется хостер, пока не известно.

1. Apache FOP, очень интересный инструмент, уже практически разобрался со всеми преобразованиями и почти получил файл .fo, все примитивы преобразуются кроме, нужного path, которого, почему-то не было в найденной схеме. И что дальше делать, снова exec и java?

В общем, может кто уже сталкивался с подобной темой, буду очень благодарен за инфу.

Comment: UPD. Хостер сказал, что Java не получится заюзать. Так что ковыряюсь дальше. О результатах сообщу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обратите внимание на [TCPDF](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/)

> TCPDF является PHP-классом генерации PDF-документов, не требующим внешних расширений.

Этот класс встраивает SVG непосредственно в векторном виде в PDF, но при желании можно и преобразовать его в растр с помощью того же ImageMagic. [Пример использования класса](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_058.phps). [Пример полученного PDF-документа с SVG-графикой](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_058.pdf).

Comment: Спасибо, как раз тестирую эту либу, правда почему-то битые пдфки получаются, но думаю разберусь.
А есть что-то похожее для PSD и PS(EPS)?

Comment: С pdf разобрался, просто библиотека оказалась требовательна к формату входного SVG. Height и Width для всего SVG принимает только в Pt или Cm, но не в px.